# insertar variable JS en html

Tags: javascript, html, variables

Me gustaría pasar el valor de la variable visitas del document ready al código html del `<li class>`

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
         visitas="active";
        });

    <div id="cursor">
             <ul class="nav nav-tabs">
        <li class="visitas"><a  data-toggle="tab"  onclick="visitasF(pagActual,idFinca); return false;">Visitas 
               T&eacute;cnico</a></li>
            </ul>
            </div>
```

Comment: ¿Dentro del li donde quieres insertarlo?

Comment: ¿Qué quieres hacer con esa variable? Intenta *alejarte* un poco del problema trata de explicar lo que intentas conseguir, lo que pides suena un poco raro

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Puedes utilizar la función `addClass()` para añadir una clase. Al igual que si quieres remover una clase puedes utilizar la función `removeClass()`.

```
$('.visitas').addClass(visitas);
```

Comment: cabe señalar que con o sin clase "active" el link será clickeable, aunque se vea gris o semitransparente.

Comment: de donde sacas que debe ser clickeable?

Comment: Estoy suponiendo que el usuario pretende habilitar o deshabilitar el link mediante una clase. A menos que la clase declare la propiedad `pointer-events`, el link seguirá siendo clickeable. Esto no tiene nada que ver con tu respuesta, es un comentario para el OP

Answer (score 2):

Caso 1: Si te refieres a hacer que **el link dentro del elemento sea no-clickeable**, y se active usando jQuery, es oportuno comentar que el atributo activo o inactivo corresponde a elementos de tipo input:

Por ejemplo:

```
<input class="mi_texto" type="text" disabled="disabled"/>
```

En cuyo caso sería

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.mi_texto').removeAttr('disabled');
));
```

Pero hoy en día algunos frameworks como Bootstrap te permiten marcar un elemento arbitrario como inactivo (no clickeable) añadiéndole la clase `disabled`. Supongo que intentas hacer algo parecido.

En ese caso usarías:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.visitas').addClass("activo");
 });
```

Y te asegurases que la clase `activo` tiene prioridad sobre la clase que lo marca como inactivo.

O bien:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('.visitas').removeClass("disabled");
 });
```

**Caso 2:**

Si te refieres a **meter el valor de una variable arbitraria a un elemento del DOM**, entonces puedes usar un data attribute:

```
var variable_cualquiera='cualquier cosa incluso un objeto';

$('.visitas').data('mi-atributo', variable_cualquiera);
```

Y luego recuperarlo como

```
var variable_almacenada = $('.visitas').data('mi-atributo');
```

La ventaja de usar un data attibute, como dice más arriba, es que puedes almacenar en ella lo que quieras, no sólo texto.

## Service Pack

Por si a alguien le entra la duda ¿Cómo hace por ejemplo bootstrap para hacer que un elemento no `input` (eg. link, div, span etc) aparezca como inactivo, añadiéndole la clase `inactive` o `disabled`?

Se haría usando `pointer-events`

```
.inactive {
   opacity: 0.7;
   color: #AAA;
   pointer-events:none;
}
```

Con eso el elemento no recibe clicks. En el caso de la pregunta que hace el OP, tendríamos que suponer que el elemento `li` parte con ese estilo, y al añadirle "active" el `pointer-events` se resetea.